# Android mapbox: How to unregister IntentReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, rx-java, mapbox

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap) {
            my_function();
        }
    });
```

in my_function() i use this subscriber:

```
GetDataSubscription = model.getData()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
```

when Subscription starts i have this errors:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
>                                                                                           at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.internal.Platform
>                                                                                           at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:112)
>                                                                                           at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:160)
>                                                                                           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
>                                                                                           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
>                                                                                           at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
>                                                                                           at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
>                                                                                           at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
>                                                                                           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
>                                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.request(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:80)
>                                                                                           at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
>                                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.setProducer(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:76)
>                                                                                           at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205)
>                                                                                           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
>                                                                                           at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
>                                                                                           at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:233)
>                                                                                           at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:225)
>                                                                                           at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8741)
>                                                                                           at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94)
>                                                                                           at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422) 
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152) 
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265) 
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
>                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
>                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

and

> MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.ConnectivityReceiver@9d069e70 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
>                                                                                       android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity .MainActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.ConnectivityReceiver@9d069e70 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
>                                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:805)
>                                                                                           at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:606)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1430)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1410)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1404)
>                                                                                           at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
>                                                                                           at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.net.ConnectivityReceiver.instance(ConnectivityReceiver.java:35)
>                                                                                           at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.MapboxAccountManager.start(MapboxAccountManager.java:53)
>                                                                                           at info.masterskaya.om.rxjavanetexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in mapbox-gl-native library, thank you for the report. I've opened a ticket to track this issue in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7176.